# Lua: get default less than function for numbers

Tags: lua, operators

I want to get the relational operator "<" as a function in Lua. 
Concretely, in a function that gets an optional comparator, I want to write sth. like this:

```
function foo( comp )
  comp = comp or "the default <"
end
```

I tried getmetatable( anyNumber ).__lt but apparently you can't get the meta table of numbers.
Also the following came to mind:

```
comp = comp or function( a, b ) return a < b end
```

But I feel like this just wraps the orginal function in yet another function. And I want it to be as efficient as possible (in Lua) in this code.

Also I'm interested in a solution just out of curiosity. What if I preferred to write less(a,b) instead of a < b.

Comment: ```debug.setmetatable(0, meta)``` changes the metatable for every number. And ```function less(a,b) return a<b end``` will return if a is less than b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua doesn't implement this as a C function, so is not accessible

Comment: @warspyking: Because that's not how Lua works. Metamethods override standard behavior, but the standard behavior is not implemented in terms of metamethods.

Comment: @Nicol Oh I misunderstood his question. I thought he wanted to override it

Comment: Ok, that's a pity but good to know. I just thought it might be possible because you can work with other "built-in functionality" like echo = print or mySine = math.sin.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could 'wrap' it, if that's applicable:

```
function less(a,b)
    return a < b
end
```